# How to call an event or API by closing browser in angular 8 using HostListener,

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to call a simple websocket clousure API on closing browser in my project,I tried to use HostListener, but its not working.Below is the code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nm7uww

### app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { HostListener,Component,OnInit  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
ngOnInit() {
      @c('window:beforeunlosd', ['$event'])
    beforeunloadHandler(event){

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is incorrect, use:

```
  @HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"])
  beforeunloadHandler(event) {
    console.log("closing");
    // rest of your code
  }
```

You can't declare a method in another method.

Comment: its not working.. and how  can you see the console once you close browser